# Where does Django logout user on expired/invalid session

Tags: django

I do some stuff on user logout, so I want to extend the method where Django does the logout on expired/invalid session but I don't find where it does it. Can you help me to point where the logout happens?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. When a session expires, it just expires, that's all.

I think your question is based on a misunderstanding about what it means to be logged in at all. Django doesn't know who's logged in at any particular time; the web is stateless, and the only time Django knows about a user is when they make a request. At that point, Django can distinguish between a user that has a valid session cookie and one that doesn't. But if the session subsequently expires, the first Django will know about it is when that user next makes a request.

Comment: I need to know the method/class where django verifies the session cookie, and decide if the request come from user "Dalailama" or not. After that I expect to find on request.user, "Dalailama" or "AnonymousUser"

Comment: That's in the authentication middleware.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the user in anyplace of view  by **request.user**. if you get a valid user info by **request.user** then the user is logged in . and this is **NULL** then the user is not logged in.

Comment: Actually is no NULL is AnonymousUser, and doesn't help me. What I wan: On user logout I ant to do some stuff, which I did, but when the session is expired -> the user is logged out, but I want to do the same thing here.

Comment: django session is handled by authentication middleware. you can't catch the session is expire or not in anywhere your code. you only get information of logged in user by request.user method